# Socket.IO display connected users list of a room

Tags: node.js, vue.js, socket.io

I have a vue.js/node/socket.io chat application. I need to create a list of online users that will stay up to date when users connect or disconnect. I'm trying using this code, but I'm not able to update the users list when someone join the room. How I can fix this?

```
'use strict';

const express = require('express');
const socketIO = require('socket.io');

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const INDEX = '/index.html';

// TODO: controllo query url
const server = express()
.use('/modules', express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules'))
.use('/assets', express.static(__dirname + '/assets'))
.use((req, res) => res.sendFile(INDEX, { root: __dirname }))
.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Listening on ${PORT}`));
const io = socketIO(server);

let connectedUsers = [];

io.on('connection', (socket) => { 
  console.log('Connected peer: '+ socket.id);
  socket.on('accessRoom', (username,room) => {
    connectedUsers = { nickname: username, id: socket.id } 
    socket.join(room, (err) => {
      socket.emit('accessStatus', 'done');
      console.log(this)
    })
    updateUsersList()
  })

  socket.emit('channelStatus', socketData)
  socket.emit('message', socket.id, 'connected')

  socket.on('message', (id, msg) => { 
    socket.broadcast.emit('message', id, msg);
  })

  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    console.log('Disconnected')
  })

  function updateUsersList(){
    socket.emit('usersList', connectedUsers)
  }

});

io.on('ping', (socket) => {
  console.log(socket);
  io.emit('pong');
});
```

vuejs code

```
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      isRegistered: false,
      isConnected: false,
      user: '',
      message: '',
      id: '',
      channel: '',
      usersList: []
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.pingServer()
    this.updateUsersList()
    io.on('pong', (data) => {
      console.log(data);
    })
    io.on('channelStatus', (data) => {
        if( data.status === 'connected' ){
          this.id = data.IHMnumber;
          this.isConnected = true;
          console.log(data);
        }
    })
    io.on('message', (from, msg) => {
      console.log(from)
      console.log(msg)
    })
  },
  methods: {
    pingServer(){
      io.emit('ping')
    },
    connect(){
      if( this.isRegistered === false){
        this.user = this.user;
        this.isRegistered = true;
        console.log(this.isRegistered);
        console.log(this.user);
        io.open()
        return this.user;
      }
    },
    updateUsersList(){
      io.on('usersList', (users) => {
        console.log(users);
        this.usersList.push(users);
      })
    },
    sendMessage(){
      console.log(this.message)
      io.emit('message', this.id ,this.message)
    }
  }
}
```

Whit this code, the user that is creating the room will not recive the users list. For the users that will join the room instead, in the console I'm able to see that they are added to the array of users, but if someone joined the room, the event will not be logged in console with the updated info. Maybe I need to refactor the code, maybe I'm calling the `updateUsersList` in the wrong place?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, if you divide users by rooms, send messages to their rooms https://socket.io/docs/server-api/#socket-to-room . Here I show you **one of** ways to solve your problem. Change type of 'connectedUsers', for example, to map, where keys will be room-name, value - array of users:

```
const connectedUsers = new Map();
```

To handle changes of user lists create method for join

```
joinToRoom(room, user) {
    // create users array, if key not exists
    if (!connectedUsers.has(room)) {
        connectedUsers.set(room, []);
    }
    // add user to room array
    connectedUsers.get(room).push(user);
    // call update function
    updateUsersList(room);
}
```

and leave room:

```
leaveRoom(room, user) {
    let userList = connectedUsers.get(room);
    // delete user
    userList = userList.filter(u => u !== user);
    // update user list
    if (!userList.length) {
        // delete key if no more users in room
        connectedUsers.delete(room);
    } else
    {
        connectedUsers.set(room, userList);
        // call update function
        updateUsersList(room);
    }
}
```

ALso change your method updateUsersList:

```
function updateUsersList(room){
    socket.to(room).emit('usersList', {
        room: room,
        users: connectedUsers.get(room)
    });
}
```

Pay attention, that we emit to event 'usersList' an object with room field for clarify, what room you should update at frontend.

The last step is call our methods:

when user joins room:

```
socket.join(room, (err) => {
  const user = resolve user from request;
  socket.emit('accessStatus', 'done');
  joinToRoom(room, user);
  console.log(this);
})
```

when user leave room: 
i don`t see the event for leave room, so you just call there leaveRoom(room, user)

Also you should create some map to compare socketId and user, to correctly handle disconnect event and call leaveRoom(room, user) method.

Comment: I need to try and test your code, I'm trying now using the `io.sockets` that seems that will reference all the sockets connection.. this will give me the ability to send the new connection update to the clients connected inside the same room, but I'm not sure if the event is fired also for other rooms different from the joined one (that isn't the expected behaviour)

Comment: For the leaveRoom function you've suggested, is there any particular code that I can apply to remove disconnected clients from the users array?

Comment: I think example in doc is suitable for you https://socket.io/docs/server-api/#Event-%E2%80%98disconnecting%E2%80%99  Just want to add, that you can map rooms variable and call inside leaveRoom function

Comment: I'm testing the code you've suggested but in node I get an error with this line `const user = resolve user from request;` any fix?The node server will not run and I get a `SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`

Comment: It was a comment)) There you can implement your logic to resolve user. I dont know your auth strategy, so i cant show you concrete example. It must be like `1) get token from request 2) in case of jwt parse token 3) find user data in db 4) set user data to const user`